# Multiple interfaces on Azure VM

Tags: networking, azure

How can I add two network interfaces to the one VM for routing and firewalling? I have had a look under Network Interfaces, located under settings, however I can't find something to add a second interface.

Thanks,
Christopher H.

Comment: since a few days its possible to add multiple IPs to a single NIC (both public/private)

Comment: @ChristopheLams It is possible, Azure has a new feature that assign multiple IP addresses to one NIC. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell)

Comment: @ChristopheLams This feature is currently in preview release. Do you want to assign multiple NICs to a VM or assign IP address to one NIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, Azure could not create multiple network interfaces VM by using Portal. You could add multiple network interface resources to a VM using PowerShell or JSON, **and it can only be done during VM creation.**

If you want to create a new VM with multiple NICs, you could use PowerShell. More information please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-deploy-multinic-arm-ps).

If you want to use your exist VM, I suggest you delete your original VM and keep the VHD. Then you could use the VHD to create multiple NICs VM. You could use the following cmdlets.

```
$rg = "jason-newgroup"
$loc = "japan east"
$nic01 = "nic01"
$nic02 = "nic02"
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name ‘jason-newgroup-vnet’ -ResourceGroupName ‘jason-newgroup’
$sub01id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub01’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
$sub02id = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name ‘sub02’ -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
$ip1 = '10.1.0.5'
$ip2 = '10.1.1.5'

$nic1 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic01 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub01id -PrivateIpAddress $ip1
$nic2 = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic02 -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -SubnetId $sub02id -PrivateIpAddress $ip2

$vmsize = "Standard_DS4_v2" 
$vmname = "jason-windows" 
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize 

$VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic1.Id -Primary
$VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $nic2.Id
$osDiskName = "jason-newtest" 
$osDiskVhdUri = "https://jasonnewgroupdisks717.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jason-windows2016920165635.vhd" 
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -windows
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Location $loc -VM $vm
```

**Notes: Please ensure the VM size you selected supports multiple NICs. More information please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes).**